# What does "brand" mean in SLDS and when is it appropriate to use slds-button--brand buttons?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, slds

SLDS (Salesforce Lightning Design System) buttons have several styling options options including the [brand](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/#flavor-base-button-brand) (blue) option. From a cursory look at Lightning Experience, the "Save" button is normally styled that way.

But what does the term "brand" mean and what would be a general principle to apply for when to use `slds-button--brand` versus for example `slds-button--neutral`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called that way because it respects branding values. If you were to change your brand's `ActionColor`, then anything styled with `--brand` would ideally get updated.

To answer your question about when to use which, I guess it depends if you're building a product other people will consume and eventually might want to brand. In that case, use `--neutral` to denote items which should always be the same regardless of branding.

*Note: I'm not sure how much branding configuration is fully implemented across the board for example in Lightning App Builder, but that's the intent at least.*

Comment: Thanks. IMHO Bootstrap's terms "primary" and "default" are a clearer approach...

Answer (score 1):

For me, brand and neutral have to be with the styling/UI only.
It depends on you which one you want to use.

But it's better to use brand for pertinent actions on your page [like Save, Edit, Create].
Being blue, one would spot the brand button faster than the neutral button. It could mean main/key action on the page.

Whereas neutral can be used for less 'important' (not the right word maybe, but you understand) like 'Cancel' / 'Close' etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering; that is pretty much what I'm assuming.